# Asus N56D and Dell U2515H: High resolution not selectable

Tags: windows-10, laptop, hdmi, amd-graphics-card, high-resolution

I connected an **Asus N56DY** to display **Dell U2515H** via an HDMI 1.4 cable. The highest available resolution is **2048x1152** if I use Windows, but on Linux **2560x1440** is available. I completely removed drivers and installed the newest ones.

How can I make **2560x1440** available under Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that AMD/ATI drivers have pixel clock limit for single-link DVI and HDMI cabels. And i found patch for removing this limit: http://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-AMD-ATI-Pixel-Clock-Patcher. For me works fine.

Answer (score 0):

That is interesting as the Dell U2515H's native resolution is 2560 x 1440 @ 60Hz, neither of which you are/have used.

You may have to build a custom resolution profile within the ATI control panel. If you haven't already I would suggest downloading the full drivers from the ATI website, not the ASUS support site. There is an [Auto-detect Tool](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/auto-detect-tool) for this.

Comment: 2460x1440 is typos i correct it. Sure i get drivers from AMD. By the way site ASUS not provide drivers for video.